# Pytorch is stuck in middle of training

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pytorch

I have this code:

my_model.py:

```
num_workers = 1

classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat',
           'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')

transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=num_workers)

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=num_workers)
```

model_tuils.py:

```
 def train_network(net, number_of_epoch, trainloader, optimizer, criterion):
        for epoch in range(number_of_epoch):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

        running_loss = 0.0
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
            inputs, labels = data

            # zero the parameter gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # forward + backward + optimize
            outputs = net(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            # print statistics
            running_loss += loss.item()
            if i % 2000 == 1999:  # print every 2000 mini-batches
                print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                      (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
                running_loss = 0.0

    print('Finished Training')
```

When I run my code, it stack inside the training loop on the first iteration, in this line:

```
for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
            inputs, labels = data     <----------------------------this line

            # zero the parameter gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()
```

When I try to find what is sticking the program, I get to this file:
/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py:

```
 def _feed(buffer, notempty, send_bytes, writelock, close, ignore_epipe,
              onerror, queue_sem):
        debug('starting thread to feed data to pipe')
        nacquire = notempty.acquire
        nrelease = notempty.release
        nwait = notempty.wait
        bpopleft = buffer.popleft
        sentinel = _sentinel
        if sys.platform != 'win32':
            wacquire = writelock.acquire
            wrelease = writelock.release
        else:
            wacquire = None

        while 1:
            try:
                nacquire()
                try:
                    if not buffer:
                        nwait() <------------------------------ This line
                finally:
                    nrelease()
```

What am i doing wrong?
My num_workers is 1 so it should not have multiple threads

Comment: 'Stuck', you mean your code throws an error, right? If so can you show us the error message with the line in your code that throws it (not PyTorch's src code).

Comment: It doesnt throw an error.
It simply comes back to nwait() (like it has not value)

Comment: 'it stack inside the training loop on the first iteration' and 'comes back to', what do you mean by that?

Comment: That the code is executing until the line  nwait(), and then repeats itself many times without returning a value